# html2canvas text-shadow bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

i have this code http://jsfiddle.net/nuu7B/2/

```
html2canvas($('#preview'), {  
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        $('#canvasImg').html('<img src="'+canvasImg+'" alt="">');
    }
});
```

and i'm using html2canvas to export image. But as you can see, the text-shadow it's not working as it should.

```
text-shadow: -2px 0 #000, 0 2px #000, 2px 0 #000, 0 -2px #000;
```

i know canvas support text-shadow but the html2canvas is the problem here..

How can I fix that? 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**html2canvas has only basic text-shadow support:**

```
// Not supported: text-shadow: -2px 0 #000, 0 2px #000, 2px 0 #000, 0 -2px #000;

// Just the basic X-offset, Y-offset, blur, color

text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #555;
```

Some options:

- Submit a pull request here: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pulls
- Position a CSS shadow styled html element over the canvas where you need it
- Experiment drawing multiple abutting shadows on html canvas to see if you can create what you need.

Comment: yup. that's a great answer thanks. if i knew how i wasn't asking here

Answer (score 0):

//This function will select each and every svg text and will apply the css

```
function styleToSVGText  () {
    var SVGTextArr = $('svg text');
    SVGTextArr.each(function (i, item) {
        $(item).css({
            'text-rendering': 'optimizeLegibility',
            'font-family': 'sans-serif',
            'text-shadow': 'transparent'
        })
    });
};
```